# How do I determine the size of a page source in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Obviously, I want to get the answer without saving the page. It seems basic, but I can't figure out how to do that. If it requires a plugin, it's ok. It would be nice if the solution would also cover styling sheets, scripts and images, associated with the page.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Open **Developer tools** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or [Settings Icon](http://www.google.com/homepage/images/dhp-step1-chrome-win.jpg) at the top-right of your browser window => `Tools` => `Developer tools`) on the needed page, switch to the **Network** tab and **reload page**.

In the **Size** column you'll see the size of everything loaded (*Documents, Stylesheets, Images, Scripts, ...*). You can enable filter to help you find out only needed stuff at the bottom-center of Developer tools frame.

Comment: Thanks! The need to reload is not so intuitive.

Comment: Kind of sucks. Right click -> 'view properties' or something similar on an already loaded page would feel much more intuitive.

Comment: Its worth adding that the total size of all requests to the server is listed at the very very bottom when you have the Network tab open. It's not immediately obvious

Comment: In a more recent version of Chrome, the total size at the bottom of the Network tab is listed as **KB/MB transferred**, which should equal the sum of the *Size* column.

Answer (score 5):

I have created my 3rd Chrome extension [Page Size Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-size-inspector/oepnndnpjiahgkljgbohnnccmokgcoln) that quickly reports page size, cache usage, network requests and load time of a web page in a convenient way.

Comment: real cool, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension called "[Quick source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb)", which caches all the resources when a page is loaded. Open the viewer (blue icon), the size (number of bytes) is shown in the navigation pane on the left.